# Ə character in Pdf

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, special-characters

I want to add paragraph with `Ə` character to pdf file. I try every Thing but Ə character is not shown in pdf file. What can I do in this situation.

My code is here:   `BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("assets/font/AZER_TM.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Paragraph tranportParagraph = new Paragraph("XƏƏƏƏƏöğııəçş\u0259", new Font(bf, 22));
        tranportParagraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.add(tranportParagraph);`

this is a picture of my AZER_TM.ttf file: [image]

As you see in the above picture There `Ə` character in the my AZER_TM.ttf file
But the character is not shown in the pdf file.

Comment: Your image spears to indicate that that symbol is displayed instead of the 'w' character. Thus, have you tried using a 'w' in your paragraph text?

Comment: If i use W character in my paragraph pdf displays Ə character, :) Thank you very much. But ğ , ı and Ş is not displayed. Can you help me for theese characters?

Comment: according to your image I can only say that those glyphs are not replacing a standard character a..zA..Z1..0 or one of the punctuation characters down there. Thus, I would propose you use a program to show you all glyphs of the font and search there, e.g. FontForge.